# Multisite 404 errors and non-www redirecting to home page

Tags: multisite, redirect, 404-error

My primary website on a multisite network was created with the `www` prefix (like `www.example.com`).

If I try to access pages without the `www` prefix (like `example.com/page-name/` instead of `www.example.com/page-name/`, I am redirected to the homepage (`www.example.com`). I would like to change this so I am redirected simply redirected to the same page URL, only with the `www` prefix.

Additionally, the 404 error page doesn't work on the primary site. No matter which non-existant URL I try (such as `www.example.com/thisdoesnotexist`), I am always redirected to the primary site home page (`www.example.com`), rather then seeing the theme's 404 page.

Here is a [link to my site](http://www.ncc.my) where you can test the issue.

Comment: `example.com/thisisalsoawrongurl` and `www.example.com/thisisawrongurl`, despite `www`, should trigger a 404 error; if not that is also a problem. Please, provide more information about URL configuration, possible .htaccess rules and any other you may consider important for this issue, otherwise it is very difficult to answer, if not impossible.

Comment: Cybmeta, i did updated the post. Kindly have a look at it. That is the original code after i created the multisite.

Comment: The .htaccess you posted is for multisite using subdirectories. See the [codex to find the .htaccess you should use for multisites using subdomains](http://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess).

Comment: Hi Cybmeta, i have updated the post. And this is the htaccess code i copied from that page you linked above. Is this what you trying to say? But, the redirect does not work no matter which code i tried.

Comment: If you've tried everything else, please make sure that your hosting service / web server supports htaccess files. If your httpd.conf does not have AllowOverride All set for your site's root directory, the htaccess file will be ignored.

Comment: The 404 error with the main site is probably due to `NOBLOGREDIRECT`, if you have that set. See trac ticket [#21573](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/21573)

Comment: Hi @shea  , thank you so much for the link provided! Now, I removed the line of `NOBLOGREDIRECT` in my `wp-config` file and the error page on main site is working but the link must be together with `www` or else it turns out to this url `http://www.example.my/wp-signup.php?new=example.com` if i type any url without "www". I tried to fix this with `.htaccess` file to make it work. But, it would affect all the subdomain redirect to www as well. Example result: `www.sub1.example.com`. I don't want this happen to my sub domain. Any php code i can implement into `wp-config` to get this resolved?

Comment: You don't need to remove the `NOBLOGREDIRECT` constant; there is a workaround to disable the buggy 404 functionality but keep the redirection of non-existant blogs. See my answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is currently a bug in the functionality that handles the `NOBLOGREDIRECT` constant, which causes 404 errors on the main site to be redirected to the value of the constant. Apparently this is the expected behaviour for sub-directory networks (`example.com/subsite`), but should not take place on subdomain networks (`subsite.example.com`).

There is a [WordPress Trac ticket (#21573)](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/21573) concerning this bug, but there is no indication on when it might be resolved. Until then, you can resolve this error yourself by removing the `maybe_redirect_404` function:

```
remove_action( 'template_redirect', 'maybe_redirect_404' );
```

This code should go in a `.php` file in the `wp-content/mu-plugins` directory. Remember to include a `<?php` tag at the beginning of the file.

Comment: Hi Shea, I don't have this folder named `mu-plugins` in current directory of `wp-content/`. Shall it be created by my own? If so, what name should i name for the `.php` file?

Comment: Yes, just create the `mu-plugins` folder inside the `wp-content` directory. The PHP file can be pretty much any name you want, though lowercase without spaces is a good way to go. For example, `custom.php`. Remember to include `<?php` at the beginning of the file.

Comment: Hi @shea, thank you so much! I have done this step. But, i am still need some further solution. Now, i have the same issue which i mentioned earlier in the comment. Which is, when i type any page's url without `www`, the site would redirect to home page instead. All the existing urls is only work when it's with `www`. Otherwise, it would redirect to homepage.

Comment: It's [not recommended](http://codex.wordpress.org/Before_You_Create_A_Network#Be_Aware) to use `www` as part of your main site URL in subdomain networks precisely this reason. At this point, it's probably best to use a [redirection on the .htaccess level](http://stackoverflow.com/q/234723/1042798)

Comment: Hi Shea, noted. How do I make changes to the setting that makes my main site from `www` to non `www` without using `htaccess`. I tried to remove the `www` from the url in the database but the result turns out to say I have a redirect loop.

Comment: Check that you have removed the www from the `DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE` constant in wp-config.php. Also, you may wish to try running [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-and-replace/) to replace `www.ncc.my` with `ncc.my` across the entire database.

Comment: Yes! I tried but i was still getting the same error when i visit my site. `You have a redirect loop`. I can consider a plugin at last if i can't get any solution. Now, trying to fix it without using a plugin if possible. :)

Comment: @Jornes the plugin is only temporary that lets you replace the old domain with the new in the database. Install it, run the replacement, and then you can remove it.

Answer (score 0):

check your `.htaccess` for

`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>`

this is the basic htaccesss parameters a wordpress installation creates during installation. Line no. 3 is important.

2. Check your database options table for proper siteurl and home value for http://www.yourdomainname.com.

Comment: Hi Shreyo Gi, the content of my .htaccess is exactly same. And, i did checked the database as well. The settings are correct. Just wondering why and looking for solution against this issue.

Comment: well, can you go to permalinks under settings and select your preferred URL structure and save it again? It happened for me once and re-saving the URL did the job.

Comment: Shreyo Gi, nothing to do with permalink. By the way, i did this setting i'm creating this site.

Comment: Jornes, please, don't say that your .htaccess is exactly the same when it is obviously not; you posted a quite different .htaccess file in your question. And Shreyo, the [.htaccess you posted is not suitable for Multiste installations](http://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess), which the case of this question.

Comment: Sorry! I did not declare clear enough previously. Yes! The .htaccess was exactly same as what Shreyo said in his answer. But, i got a new code from somewhere else while i was searching for the solution. So, i added it on. The code i copied and pasted on updated part is the new code. But, it doesn't work as well.